# Moving from fancyvrb to listing – need to reconstruct my font settings

Tags: fonts, listings, fancyvrb

I have happily used the `fancyvrb` package with the `Verbatim` environment so far, but I want to change my figures to use the `listing` package with the `lstlisting` environment in order to have bold-faced keywords which improve readability.

Unfortunately, I have no clue to adjust the listing settings to get the same (very nice) font I had before with fancyvrb...

Here is my fancy verb settings:

```
% fancy verb
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{relsize}
\fvset{fontfamily=fvm}
\fvset{fontsize=\relsize{-2}}
\fvset{baselinestretch=1.3}
```

And here for listings, using the Scala language:

```
% listings
\usepackage{listings}
\lstdefinelanguage{scala}{ % "define" Scala
  morekeywords={abstract,case,catch,class,def,do,else,extends,false,final,%
    finally,for,if,implicit,import,match,mixin,new,null,object,override,package,%
    private,protected,requires,return,sealed,super,this,throw,trait,true,try,%
    type,val,var,while,with,yield},
  otherkeywords={=>,<-,<\%,<:,>:,\#,@},
  sensitive=true,
  morecomment=[l]{//},
  morecomment=[n]{/*}{*/},
  morestring=[b]",
  morestring=[b]',
  morestring=[b]"""
}
\lstset{ % activate the language and predefine settings
    language=scala,%
    fontadjust=true,%
    columns=[c]fixed,%
    keepspaces=true,%
    basewidth={0.58em, 0.53em},%
    tabsize=2,%
    basicstyle=\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.95}\ttfamily,%
    commentstyle=\itshape,%
    keywordstyle=\bfseries,%
    mathescape=true,%
    escapechar=€,%
    captionpos=b,%
    framerule=0.3pt,%
    firstnumber=0,%
    numbersep=1.5mm,%
    numberstyle=\tiny,%
}
```

And here is the document body contrasting both:

```
\documentclass{article}
% ... paste the fancy verb and listing settings from above here
\begin{document}

\begin{Verbatim}
object Stream {
  def cons[A](hd: A, tl: => Stream[A]) = new Stream[A] {
     def head = hd
     lazy val tail = tl
     ...
  }
}
\end{Verbatim}

\begin{lstlisting}
object Stream {
  def cons[A](hd: A, tl: => Stream[A]) = new Stream[A] {
     def head = hd
     lazy val tail = tl
     ...
  }
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Neither does the font of listing look remotely like the T1/fancyvrb one, nor does LaTeX seem to pay attention to setting the keywords in bold-face:

[image]

I guess I need to change the `basicstyle` entry, but how?

Comment: Just a short note: Did you notice, that you can use `listings` _together_ with `fancyvrb`? See the according section in documentation of `listings`.

Comment: Much better: Provide a self-answer with all bells and whistles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so this actually the answer of @Speravir :)

All that is needed is the following listing settings:

```
\lstset{
  language=scala,%
  commentstyle=\itshape,%
  keywordstyle=\bfseries,%
  fancyvrb=true % !!
}
```

Then everything already set in `\begin{Verbatim}...\end{Verbatim}` benefits from the keyword and comment highlighting.

Comment: One should read the section “Interface to `fancyvrb`” in the `listings` documentation for respective caveats.